# Facebook iOS-sdk and posting a local (UI)Image

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios4, facebook-ios-sdk

I have successfully used photos.upload api to upload local images to the users album.

How to upload local images with formatted links? The `photos.upload` does support adding the caption text, but I can't embed html-links to the caption. Is there a way to do this using perhaps the Graph-api?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the caption itself, but here is a way to post the image along with a message to the user's wall.  The message text can have imbedded links in it with no problem.

```
Facebook* fb = [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] facebook];
NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed: @"A.jpg"], 90);
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [fb accessToken], 
              @"access_token", 
              @"some message here...with a link http://www.google.com",
              @"message", 
              imageData, 
              @"source", 
              nil];

[fb requestWithGraphPath: @"me/photos" 
               andParams: params 
           andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
             andDelegate: self];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The tricky part for me is to get formatted links in the message (or caption) and for that I don't have a solution.